# Java EE 7 dynamic user roles

Tags: java, security, dynamic, authentication, glassfish-4

My problem is the integration of a security system in my java ee 7 web application with glass fish 4. I have seen several examples of authentication declarative but also programmatic but none of them covered my problem. 
In my application i have 2 groups which need authentication.

- ADMIN = All access rights
- EMPLOYEE = Only a subset of the admin rights.

The problem is that the users of these groups are always changing so i want to store all the users in a DB table. Also i want to use @RolesAllowed annotation and programmatic security like ctx.isCallerInRole("ADMIN") because of simplicity.

Summary: I want to store all users in a database table and i want to use @RolesAllowed annotation and programmatic security like ctx.isCallerInRole("ADMIN"). Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. E.g. look for the "JDBC Realm".

Here is an older tutorial. It might still work with GlassFish 4, though:

https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/jdbcrealm_in_glassfish

Comment: so with JDBC Realm i can also use these annotations?

Comment: Yes, the realm used is independent of the annotations in the project.